# Upgrade from prestashop 1.6.1.9 to 1.7

Tags: upgrade, migrate, prestashop-1.7

Is it posible to upgrade from prestashop 1.6.1.9 to 1.7? Where is the official documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time it's not possible. Check comments here:
http://build.prestashop.com/news/prestashop-1-7-0-0-released/

Probably it will be available in the future; at this time you can only export products, categories and customers from 1.6.x to 1.7.x

**Update 2017/03/27**: available since today http://build.prestashop.com/news/updated-1-click-upgrade-module/

Comment: this module is not able to upgrade from 1.6 to 1.7. Version 3 apparently does but v3 will not work on prestashop 1.6

Answer (score 2):

Direct upgrade is impossible
But you can migrate your website data to 1.7 with this free module: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/820013-migrate-or-upgrade-prestashop-16-or-other-versions-to-17-%E2%80%93-free-module/

Answer (score 0):

We have developed a data migration module PrestaShop 1.6 to 1.7, you can migrate your products, customers, orders, couriers, categories, manufacturers and much more.
https://addons.prestashop.com/en/data-migration-backup/29736-1-click-prestashop-upgrade-16-to-17.html

Answer (score -1):

This module provides an automated method to upgrade your shop to the latest PrestaShop version : https://addons.prestashop.com/en/data-migration-backup/5496-1-click-upgrade.html

Comment: this module can't migrate from 1.6 to 1.7 actually